# Multiple mouse problems with source engine

Tags: macos, mouse, source-engine

I have two problems with my mouse when playing some of the newer games on source engine (CS:GO, Gmod.) Firstly, every now and then it'll turn me 180 degrees for no reason, and secondly, clicking will disable looking around for about a fifth of a second.

I know this isn't a problem with my actual mouse, because I've tried using another mouse and the same problem happened.

Any idea why this is happening, or how to fix it? I'm on Mac, by the way.

Comment: Issue has been reported here: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Source-1-Games/issues/2153

Comment: Issue has been reported here: http://steamcommunity.com/app/440/discussions/0/135509314047212846/

Comment: Issue mentioned here: https://www.reddit.com/r/valve/comments/5sumk9/major_bug_in_all_source_games_on_macos/?st=j0jvmn5p&sh=67fcb01e